# Attach a jQuery function to an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to attach a jQuery function to an AJAX response. The JavaScript file content is the following.

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.rembourcement').find( ".button" ).click(function() {
         var nb=$(this).data('ligne');
         //
         if($('.bloks_sous_lignehold'+nb).is(':visible')){
            $( this).removeClass('button_active');
            $(this).closest('.ligne').removeClass('bg-washed-green2 shadow-1');
         }else{
            $( this ).addClass('button_active');
            $(this).closest('.ligne').addClass('bg-washed-green2 shadow-1');
         }
         $( ".bloks_sous_lignehold"+nb ).slideToggle( "slow" );
     });
}(jQuery));
```

In the AJAX callback, I used the following code, without success.

```
$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$elem = [
   '#type' => 'container',
   '#attributes' => ['id' => 'table-wrapper'],
   '#theme' => 'Mcfiltered',
   '#mc_build_data' => $mc_build_data
];
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#table-wrapper', $renderer->render($elem)));
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('.rembourcement .button', 'click'));
return $response;
```

This doesn't seem to work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use Drupal.behaviors, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, I have functions like the below in my JS file.

```
$(document).bind('myFunction', function() {
     //
});
```

In my module, I then have the below.

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('html', 'trigger', array('myFunction'));
```

Maybe Drupal 8 would be similar.

**Edit:** If you're here looking to run a jQuery function after Ajax, like the title asks, ignore the downvote. Drupal Behaviours may be what you're looking for, but if it's just Dom manipulation, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Niall, but i used drupal 8's [behaviors](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/load-javascript-drupal-drupalbehaviors?p=2512) which is a cool approach to solve this issue. i tweaked my Js to the following:

```
(function($, Drupal)
{
// I want some code to run on page load, so I use Drupal.behaviors
Drupal.behaviors.smenoModule = {
    attach:function(context, settings){
     
        // Ensure that this behavior is only attached once to the window.
        $($('.rembourcement').find( ".button" ), context).once().click(function () { //$(context).find('[data-mybehavior]')
            var nb=$(this).data('ligne');
            //
            if($('.bloks_sous_lignehold'+nb).is(':visible')){
                $( this).removeClass('button_active');
                $(this).closest('.ligne').removeClass('bg-washed-green2 shadow-1');
            }
            else{
                $( this ).addClass('button_active');
                $(this).closest('.ligne').addClass('bg-washed-green2 shadow-1');
            }
            $( ".bloks_sous_lignehold"+nb ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        });
    }
};
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

what the above code does is the same as jQuery's ready function, the content is executed on the page load but also:

> After the AJAX Form API has submitted a form.
>
> When an AJAX request returns a command that modifies the HTML, such as ajax_command_replace().

and to ensure that the functions are called only once we use once().

check out [this](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal) good article

PS: I no longer needed this lign, so i removed it:

> $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('.rembourcement .button', 'click'));

Comment: Based on your description, it's quite different. My suggestion was for a function that only runs after Ajax. Anyways, it sounds like you got what you needed.